Why typescript doesn't produce errors with generic parameter of argument in class?
I want to define class with generic parameter T and some methods operating with instances of the same class with the same parameter T.
But it doesn't produce type errors as I expect.
Basically I want to something like this:
class C<T extends "a" | "b"> {
  foo(b: C<T>): C<T> {
    return b;
  }
}

I want this to ensure safety, but typescript doesn't produce an error on the last line as I expect.
a.foo has type (C<"a">) => C<"a"> but accepts C<"b">
const a = {} as C<"a">;
const b = {} as C<"b">;
a.foo(b);

Simpler example without class in argument produces error.
class D<T extends "a" | "b"> {
  foo(b: T): T {
    return b;
  }
}

const a = {} as D<"a">;
a.foo("b");


Your C<T> does not depend structurally on T. That is, C<"a"> is identical to C<"b">, and therefore they are interchangeable. If you want to break that identity you need to give C some kind of actual structural dependency on T, like giving it a property of type T, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yes, thank you!
I wanted to use this parameter as a safety tag, to have two identical classes what can't be used together.
I guess I will just add
_methodWhatUsesTag(tag: Tag) {     return tag; }

I'll write up an answer here when I get a chance. Probably tomorrow morning (it's sleepytime in my time zone now)

TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal. That means two types X and Y are considered the same if they have the same shape or structure, even if they have different declarations or different names.  This holds true for generics as well; F<X> and F<Y> might be the same type even if X and Y are different types, since it depends on the structure of F<T>. If, for example, you have type F<T> = string, where T is completely ignored, then F<X> and F<Y> are the same no matter what X and Y are.
So we can't just assume that C<"a"> and C<"b"> are different types merely because "a" and "b" are different. We have to check. The instance type of C looks like
interface C<T> {
    foo(b: C<T>): C<T>;
}

It's recursive. That makes things more complicated. I don't think this is documented anywhere officially anymore, but the outdated/deprecated TypeScript language spec says that when you compare two types you start off assuming they're compatible, and then if you recurse down and hit the same pair of types, you can just treat them as compatible. This lets TypeScript see type X = {a: X} and type Y = {a: Y} as structurally identical.
By this metric, then, C<T> is completely structurally independent of T. If you write type CA = C<"a"> and type CB = C<"b">, then you'd be comparing interface CA { foo(b: CA): CA } with interface CB { foo(b: CB): CB }. Those are structurally identical. So C<T> might as well be type C<T> = string for all the good T is doing.
So a.foo(b) succeeds because a and b are of the same type.

If you don't want that behavior, then you should make sure C<T> is structurally dependent on T. The easiest way to do this is to give it a property of type T:
class C<T extends "a" | "b"> {
    constructor(public t: T) { }
    foo(b: C<T>): C<T> {
        return b;
    }
}

Here I've used a parameter property to give C<T> a t property of type T that needs to be passed to the constructor.  So the instance type of C looks like
interface C<T> {
    t: T;
    foo(b: C<T>): C<T>;
}

Now we can write:
const a = new C("a");
const b = new C("b");
a.foo(b); // error!
//    ~ <-- Argument of type 'C<"b">' is 
// not assignable to parameter of type 'C<"a">'.

and you get the desired behavior.  That's because a.t and b.t are of different types.  The comparison of C<"a"> to C<"b"> can distinguish them immediately, without even needing to recurse.
Playground link to code
